# Create textindex on property of embedded list object with MongoDB C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm trying to avoid using magic strings, but I can't get to a solution.
I've got two objects:

```
public class Class1
    {
        public BsonObjectId id { get; set; }
        //...
        public List<Class2> class2List = new List<FormerJob>();
    }

    public class Class2
    {
        public string property{ get; set; }
        //...

    }
```

And in my code:

```
var keys = Builders<Class1>.IndexKeys.Text("class2List.property")
textIndex = mongoCollection.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(keys, options));
```

Obvously the following doesn't work in code:

```
var keys = Builders<Class1>.IndexKeys.Text(p => p.class2List.property)
```

because class2List is a List of Class2

I've tried to avoid using "class2List.property" with:

```
var keys = Builders<Class1>.IndexKeys.Text(p => p.class2[0].property)
```

but it results a textindex in Mongo like: *class2List.0.property* instead of: *class2List.property*

How can I create this textindex with lambdas?